# YComb spreading out multiple sticks

Tags: pgfplots

I have the following graph:

```
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y dir = reverse,
     width=12cm,
     height=10cm, 
     xtick={1,...,6}, 
     ytick={-1,...,-1000},
     ymax=-600,
     xlabel = Number of tasks trained,
     ylabel = Cost
     ]
\addplot+[ycomb, very thick] coordinates {(1, -612) (2, -612)   (3, -611) (4,-611) (5, -611)};
\addplot+[ycomb, very thick] coordinates {          (2, -611.5) (3, -611) (4,-611) (5, -610.5)};
\addplot+[ycomb, very thick] coordinates {                      (3, -612) (4,-611) (5, -610.9)};
\addplot+[ycomb, very thick] coordinates {                                (4,-613) (5, -613)};
\addplot+[ycomb, very thick] coordinates {                                         (5, -612.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The problem is that the sticks from all combs are overlapping. Is there a way to spread them out like in a barchart ?

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! It is best to complete your code snippet to a complete minimal document showing how you load `pgfplots`.

Comment: The obvious solution, albeit a somewhat tedious one, is to modify the x-coordinates, so I'm guessing you'd want something more automatic. But, e.g. for x=1, should the line be where it is now, or do you want to shift all the bars in the same plot the same amount relative to the given x-value?

Comment: I would be happy with either a constant shift for all lines in one plot or just a shift around each individual point. I did fix the coordinates manually for now but the is quite tedious as i do have more than one graph where i need to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semi-automatic, add an `xshift` to each `\addplot`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[y dir = reverse,
     width=12cm,
     height=10cm, 
     xtick={1,...,6}, 
     ytick={-1,...,-1000},
     ymax=-600,
     xlabel = Number of tasks trained,
     ylabel = Cost
     ]
\addplot+[ycomb, very thick,xshift=-4mm] coordinates {(1, -612) (2, -612)   (3, -611) (4,-611) (5, -611)};
\addplot+[ycomb, very thick,xshift=-2mm] coordinates {          (2, -611.5) (3, -611) (4,-611) (5, -610.5)};
\addplot+[ycomb, very thick] coordinates {                      (3, -612) (4,-611) (5, -610.9)};
\addplot+[ycomb, very thick,xshift=2mm] coordinates {                                (4,-613) (5, -613)};
\addplot+[ycomb, very thick,xshift=4mm] coordinates {                                         (5, -612.5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```